# Django Rest Api filter field's select options based on request.user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a django rest framework api which involves displaying a list of campaigns and allowing user to create new campaign.

On the browsable api, I managed to display the list of campaigns that I wanted as well as have a form for the user to create new campaign.

This is a screenshot of the form that the user is using for creating new campaign.

[A screenshot of the form on browsable API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2bpC.png)

While everything is working, I faced an issue that I do not have any idea how to solve even after reading the documentation.

As you can see on the screenshot, there is a clist field that allows user to select the contact list he/she want the campaign invitations to be sent to. However, I want to make sure only the contact lists created by the user's company are shown in that field (currently, all the contact lists from different companies can be selected).

Here is the codes in the api.py:

```
class EditCampaignViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EditCampaignSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}

    def list(self, request, p_uuid=None, type=None, *args, **kwargs):
        company = request.user.profile.company
        queryset = Campaign.objects.filter(company=company,
                                           product__uuid=p_uuid,
                                           deleted=False,
                                           campaign_type=type)\
                                   .order_by('-created')\
                                   .prefetch_related('user__profile')
        serializer = EditCampaignSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is the serializers.py

```
class EditCampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('id', 'campaign_id', 'campaign_type', 'name', 'product', 'description', 'status', 'actual_file_name',
              'pdf_file', 'download', 'header', 'body', 'footer', 'company', 'created', 'updated', 'deleted',
              'clist', 'user')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'campaign_id', 'campaign_type', 'product', 'status', 'actual_file_name', 'company', 'created',
                        'updated', 'deleted', 'user')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditCampaignSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        self.fields['clist'] = ChoiceField(choices=CList.objects.filter(company=user.profile.company))
```

I am still pretty new to django rest framework, so please pardon me if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `get_serializer_context` and instead updated my codes to this.

```
serializer = EditCampaignSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': self.request})
```

Now, the request is passed to the serializer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your models look like, but something like this will work:

views.py:

```
class EditCampaignViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}
```

serializers.py:

```
class EditCampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        ...
        ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditCampaignSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        self.fields['clist'] = ChoiceField(choices=ContactList.objects.filter(company__user=user))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But do I have to add anything on the ModelViewSet?

Comment: If the context["request"] above doesn't work, then you should override your view to include the request in serializer context, like this:     def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply once again. But I got a KeyError 'request' after adding in your answers, am I still missing something?

Comment: i edited the answer, did you update the view,  get_serializer_context to return the request

Comment: yes, I already did that. i still got the error after adding the get_serializer_context